# call a method in an activity from a "normal" class

Tags: android

I have one main activity that handles all the UI stuff. In the activity i have a `ListView` which is in a `SlidingDrawer`, above that are 4 `TextView`s.
I want to change the text of the 4 `TextView`s once i click on an item from the `ListView`.
I get the text from an online database, so i put the code for that in an extra class.
I created a reference to the workerclass:

```
final OneTopic ot = new OneTopic();
```

In my onClickListener I call the method from the workerclass

```
ot.postData(position);
```

At the beginning of the workerclass i have a reference to the main class

```
Main main = new Main();
```

when the worker class is finished, it calls the method that updates the UI in the Activity.

```
main.displayText(body, title, date, poster);
```

The method its calling looks like this:

```
public void displayText(String body, String title, String date, String poster) {
    tx_body.setText(Html.fromHtml(body));
    tx_title.setText(title);
    tx_date.setText(date);
    tx_poster.setText(poster);
}
```

If I do this my app force closes once it tries to set the text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is "the workerthread", where is stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the beginning of the workerclass i have a reference to the main
>   class
>
> ```
> Main main = new Main();
> ```

That's actually creating a new instance of your Main class, not getting a reference to the current one. If you want a reference to your activity from your worker thread, then you need to pass in your activity as a parameter.

```
ot.postData(Main.this, position);
```

Comment: Thanks this did the job :-)
but I have three methods that call each other one after another, so I have to pass the reference around through the 3 methods. Is this okay?. I'm not really happy with that.

Comment: That's recommended if you need to do it this way actually. The other option is to pass Main into the constructor of your worker class and assign it as a class variable, but you run the risk of keeping a hanging reference to that Activity even when it gets destroyed. In your case, that probably wouldn't happen, but it's good practice to only throw activity around where you absolutely need it and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your entire code, I see two possibilities:

1. Your WorkerThread is not running in the UI Thread and you can only update UI objects from within the UI Thread.  Check out the [Worker Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) topic in the Android dev guide.  Basically the code for displayText() is what needs to go in the Runnable in the example I just provided you.
2. I am slightly troubled at this statement:

   At the beginning of the workerclass i have a reference to the main class `Main main = new Main();`

   If Main is your activity, then you **should not** be constructing a new one.  You need a reference to the Activity instance that started the worker thread.

Hope this helps.  I see you're new to StackOverflow.  If this answers your question, please mark it as accepted.  Good luck!